# FileUpload control - .net 4.0, vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Ive never used this control before and now have a requirement to do so.
Ive got the control on a webform with a button to copy the filepath to a textbox,
but how do I actually copy over the file to the destination folder?
Any hints appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the control's `SaveAs` method.

Comment: just noticed that in a book! but thanks for the reply, appreciated